# How to exchange data with server from mobile web app

Tags: html, jquery, cordova, cross-platform

Hi I have to develop a mobile application using cross platform technology(HTML,CSS,JAVASCRIPT) wherein I need to send data to server and receive data from server.so I thought to use ajax so I tried below given code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").load("http://10.16.10.188/login/Hello.txt");
      });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>
    <button>Get External Content</button>

    </body>
    </html>
```

The above code is working when I keep this html and text file on wamp server in same directory. but its not working when I keep this html file in my android asset folder and text file on server.it is not giving any response.could someone please help me to get this done.thank you so much

Comment: You need to enable CORS on the server: http://enable-cors.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by using jsonp in below given code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="jquery-1.10.1.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
    $.ajax({
    url:"http://10.16.10.188/login/loginValidator.php",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success:function(data,status){
    if(status=='success')
    {
    alert("Data: " + data.fullname + "\nStatus: " + status);
    var val = data.fullname;
    $("#imchanged").html(val);
    }
    }
    }); 
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>
    <button id="imchanged">Get External Content</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Below is loginValidator.php code where my html points.

```
    <?php
    $array = array(
    'fullname' => 'Jeff Hansen',
    'address' => 'somewhere no.3'
    );
    $data = json_encode($array);
    echo $_GET['callback']."(".$data.")";
    ?>
```

Using above given code I am able to invoke php file from mobile emulator and get the response from server.